# Drivers not working for a pass through GPU

Tags: qemu, linux-kvm, virt-manager

I recently made a Virtual Machine using virt-manager, and I pass through a GPU. When I turn on the guest (Windows 10). It disables the device and locks the screen resolution to 800x600. I have no clue what is going on.
Thanks for your help!

Edits:
[A screenshot from Windows (Graphics card Properties)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l04PO.png)

[A screenshot from Windows (Device Manager)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmw2G.png)

[A screenshot from Windows (Display Settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoSJ4.png)

Comment: You need two graphics cards for that. Do you?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have an integrated card on my Intel i7, and a GTX 1650TI.